# How do I set Team City build number using build number from another build config?

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

I have 2 build configurations for my project in Team City 7. One project is called Development, the other is Hotfixes. Our version numbers look something like `2.2.140.0`.
The third number, `140` corresponds to the build number of the development build. We would like for the last number in the sequence to correspond to the build number of the hotfixes build. Is there a way to set the hotfixes build configuration to pull the build number from the development build config? The end goal is that every time development is built it looks like this: `2.2.<buildnumber>.0` and every time hotfixes is built it looks like this: `2.2.<devBuildNumber>.<buildnumber>`.

Bonus: if we could have the dev build reset the build counter in hotfixes that would be awesome but I'm not entirely sure that is possible.

Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, "chained builds" feature will help in your case? http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/How+To...#HowTo...-Sharethebuildnumberforbuildsinachainbuild

Comment: I don't want them to cause each other to build though. I don't want them relying on other builds, I just want a way that we can tell our hotfix builds apart from our dev builds by looking at the version number of the dll generated.